# PowerShell: Copy-Item fails despite the same process working with Windows Explorer

Tags: powershell, file-copying

I have a script that needs to copy files on a regular basis (every hour). I can open the source and destination folder using windows explorer and copy the file without issue.

However, if I try the same thing in PowerShell I get an Access to the path is denied error. I've checked the permissions on the share and I have full access. Why does this fail through PowerShell?

Copy-Item command:

```
Copy-Item \\idmststtrm2\tns_admin$\tnsnames.ora -Destination \\bts13r2b\tnsnames -Force
```

Errors:

```
Copy-Item : Access to the path '\\bts13r2b\tnsnames\tnsnames.ora' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item \\idmststtrm2\tns_admin$\tnsnames.ora -Destination \\bts13r2b\tnsnames ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\idmststtrm2\tns_admin$\tnsnames.ora:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Access to the path '\\bts13r2b\tnsnames\tnsnames.ora' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item \\idmststtrm2\tns_admin$\tnsnames.ora -Destination \\bts13r2b\tnsnames ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Edits:

When I execute a `Get-ChildItem` against the destination path, I'm able to see the folder contents.

Results from get-item:

```
get-item \\idmststtrm2\tns_admin$\tnsnames.ora

Directory: \\idmststtrm2\tns_admin$


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
-a---         3/10/2017   8:49 AM      14143 tnsnames.ora                                                              


get-item \\bts13r2b\tnsnames\tnsnames.ora

Directory: \\bts13r2b\tnsnames


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
-a---          3/8/2017   9:51 AM      15991 tnsnames.ora 

get-item \\bts13r2b\tnsnames

Directory: 


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----         3/21/2017  11:14 AM            tnsnames
```

Tried using xcopy:

```
xcopy \\idmststtrm2\tns_admin$\tnsnames.ora \\bts13r2b\tnsnames\tnsnames.ora

Access is denied.
```

Comment: In your PowerShell window run the `whoami` just to check it is running as the correct credentials.

Comment: Just tested it. The correct credentials appear.

Comment: Can you do a `Get-ChildItem` on the same items? Wondering if this is permissions to a specific file, rather than the directory as a whole

Comment: _`-Force` switch indicates that `Copy-Item` cmdlet will copy items that cannot otherwise be changed, such as copying over a **read-only file** or alias._  This does not cover `system` flagged destination file.

Comment: @gvee `Get-ChildItem` on the path directory works without error.

Comment: @JosefZ I've tried using the `-Force` switch as well but still receive the error.

Comment: Does `xcopy.exe` work?  How about `[System.IO.File]::Copy()`?  If you're using a scheduled task, does the user account you're using have the "Log on as batch job" permission on the host as well as both the source and destination systems?

Comment: Pleas share output from `(Get-Item filepath\tnsnames.ora).Attributes` for both source and destination _filepath_.

Comment: @BaconBits Xcopy also receives Access denied error. I'm unsure how to test the System.IO.File method.  For now I'm avoiding scheduled tasks until I can execute it manually without error

Comment: @JosefZ the question has been updated with the output.

Comment: `(Get-Acl  filepath\tnsnames.ora).Access | ft -AutoSize -Wrap` - double check your access rights, again for both source and destination `filepath`.

Comment: I don't see my account in the permissions. It looks like the share permissions were setup but the local NTFS permissions were missing.

Comment: _I don't see my account in the permissions._ You are `BUILTIN\Users` then,  supposedly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is due to permissions writing to a network share. While the share permissions were set correctly, the NTFS permissions were missing. A system administrator will need to ensure both sets of permissions allow for the account to write to the folder. Once this was updated correctly the script was able to perform a copy to the network share.

Comment: Many thanks for this! This was my issue too; updating the security permissions on the folder then allowed me to copy over the files

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I had a hair-pulling experience trying to get a scheduled job (running as a GMSA) to work calling a .ps1 using Copy-Item and getting the same "Access to the path ... is denied" error. I checked and double-check permissions on the remote shares - both Share permissions and NTFS permissions. It ran successfully with my login, it ran successfully with Admin login.

Finally, just for grins, I changed the Share permissions from "All Users" to "Everyone" and it started working! Therefore, it appears that GMSA accounts are not part of "All Users". I would have never guessed!

Hopefully this saves someone 10 hours of fruitless labor...

Answer (score 2):

You have the correct idea, but what if you try using the 'Administrative Share' to access the other system.

Created some standard variables: `$Source` and `$Target`. Now we use `Get-ChildItem` and the switch `-Path` to grab the file or directory we need. Then we use `Copy-Item` and the switch `-Force` to send the file to the other server. This method should work, but will describe another method.

I assume it would look something like this.

```
$Source = "\\idmststtrm2\c$\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tns_admin$\tnsnames.ora"
$Target="\\bts13r2b\c$\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source | Copy-Item -Destination $Target -Force
```

Another option is to make sure that you first have **write access** to both shared directories. Once that is verified, we run the following:

```
$Source="\\idmststtrm2\tns_admin$\tnsnames.ora"
$Target="\\bts13r2b\tnsnames"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source | Copy-Item -Destination $Target -Force
#(Get-Acl $Source).Access #Verify $Source Access
#(Get-Acl $Target).Access #Verify $Target Access
```

Let us know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening powershell as an administrator, some times that causes this issue

Comment: I wish it was that easy. This is definitely not a run PowerShell as an administrator issue. Additionally I can copy files to other servers\folders just fine.