# Powershell copy-item not working with azure automation

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Trying to execute ps script on azure vm's using azure automation using the approach defined at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62258063/1014275.  Script below does copy files between azure vm's. Both Vm's are in same subnet and if we run the copy-item command from VM powershell it copies the files to target VM folder. The same script executes successfully with azure automation runbooks, but without copying files.

Script used:

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\folder\sample.txt -Destination \\\VmHostname\C$\folder -Force
```

Updated 1: The script throws exception as below.

```
Failed
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\folder\file.txt Destination: 
\\vmhostname\C$\folder". Copy-Item : You can't connect to the file share because it's not secure. This share requires the obsolete SMB1 
protocol, which is unsafe and could expose your system to attack.
Your system requires SMB2 or higher.
```

Update 2:

run the below ps command (Solved update 1 issue)

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol
```

after this we are getting below error

```
Failed
 Copy-Item : Access is denied
At C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\1.1.5\Downloads\script17.ps1:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path C:\folder\file.txt -Destination \\vmhostname ...
```

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: Maybe related to this question? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981669/5344880] Also, I think you already know that SMB1 is deprecated and is not recommended. This link shows how to detect, enable / disable SMB protocols. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3]

Comment: Got working with Azure Automation Hybrid Worker Setup and RunAs Account.

Comment: @user1014275 -  Can you clarify the exact steps you took to resolve the issue? Are the steps documented in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-windows-hrw-install#windows-hybrid-runbook-worker-installation-and-configuration

Comment: @FemiSulu:: Yes. Also take a look at this video https://youtu.be/Yj0LDaGZekE